# Renaming column (attribute) name using GeoTools and shapefile:

Tags: shapefile, geotools

I'm accessing exiting shapefile with:

```
File file = new File("file_name.shp");
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("url", file.toURI().toURL());
DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);
```

or directly the associated dbf:

```
FileDataStore myData = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
SimpleFeatureSource source = myData.getFeatureSource();
SimpleFeatureType schema = source.getSchema();
```

but in both ways I don't know how to proceed in order to rename the column (attribute) names. I haven't found solution in the [Shapefile Plugin](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html) documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a new `FeatureType` (schema) for your output `DataStore` with the new column names and then copy the features to the new type and write them out.

Something like this will do it:

```
DataStore inputDataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(Collections.singletonMap("url", inFile.toURI().toURL()));

    String inputTypeName = inputDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
    SimpleFeatureType inputType = inputDataStore.getSchema(inputTypeName);
    FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> source = inputDataStore.getFeatureSource(inputTypeName);

    FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> inputFeatureCollection = source.getFeatures();

    // Create new schema

    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    builder.add(inputType.getGeometryDescriptor()); // first the_geom
    builder.add(inputType.getDescriptor("STATE_NAME"));
    builder.setName("Output");
    SimpleFeatureType outType = builder.buildFeatureType();

    /*
     * Alternative method
     * try { outType = DataUtilities.createSubType(inputType, new String[]{"the_geom","STATE_NAME"}); } catch (SchemaException e) {}
     */
    // Copy
    ArrayList<SimpleFeature> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = (SimpleFeatureIterator) inputFeatureCollection.features()) {
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature f = DataUtilities.reType(outType, itr.next());
        list.add(f);
      }
    }
    FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> outputFeatureCollection = DataUtilities.collection(list);
    // Write
    ShapefileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();
    ShapefileDataStore newDataStore = (ShapefileDataStore) dataStoreFactory
        .createNewDataStore(Collections.singletonMap("url", outFile.toURI().toURL()));

    newDataStore.createSchema(outType);
    String typeName = newDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

    SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) newDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

    featureStore.addFeatures(outputFeatureCollection);
  }
```